# Настройка https в nginx без сертификата

Tags: nginx

Начну с того что я фронтенд. Для тестирования функционала мне нужно уметь внедрять свой код на https сайты.

Могу ли я как-то настроить на локальной машине nginx чтобы он отдавал статику по https. Чтобы иметь возможность подключать скрипты в консоле браузера по https?
Мне даже не нужно чтобы https был валидным, просто чтобы в протоколе было написано "https://". Сертификата у меня нет, может быть есть какой-то хак для этого, был бы благодарен за пример конгфига

Answer (score 2):

протокол [https](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) — это «протокол http поверх протоклов [ssl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) или [tls](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS)».

и прежде чем можно будет получить хоть какие-то байты по протоколу http, клиент и сервер вначале должны установить соединение по протоколам ssl или tls, для работы которых как раз и **обязательно** требуется так называемый «сертификат» (который представляет собой пару из открытого и закрытого ключей).

именно этого ожидают (соответствующие требованиям стандартов) клиенты.

попытка их «обмануть», не устанавливая ssl/tls соединение, не имеет практического смысла (ну, только если вы не, к примеру, исследователь уязвимостей).

---

для тестирования можете сгенерировать само-подписанный сертификат. это если нет возможности потратить чуть больше времени на получение «хорошего» сертификата от, например, [letsencrypt](/questions/tagged/letsencrypt).