# Обратный прокси без необходимости установки SSL на нем

Tags: nginx

Появилась потребность в обратном прокси для сайта с SSL сертификатом, да бы не устанавливать сам сертификат каждый раз на обратный прокси.

Примерная, требуемая схема работы:

```
A(веб-сервер с SSL) <> B(Обратный прокси) <> С(Клиент)
```

На чем можно реализовать что-то подобное?

Comment: Обычно это делается наоборот. Ставится на Nginx валидный сертификат, а на сервере за ним либо самоподписанный сертификат либо вообще отсутствие ssl (если запрос перенаправляется по сети без участия интернета).

Comment: [идентичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/826318/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в конкретно моем случае, нет цели изменять web-страницу сайта. Но, нужно ставить сертификат на веб-сервер, а за ним уже иметь обратный прокси без сертификатов.

Comment: ага. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826339/178576) для вас остался непонятен. ну, попробуйте задать другой вопрос.

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Какой-нибудь `proxy_pass https://адрессервера` отлично работает и соединяется с веб-сервером имеющим SSL.

Comment: @andreymal Но при этом же у прокси нужно будет устанавливать сертификат для https, или я не прав?

Comment: @Zaken нужно, если вы хотите, чтобы клиент тоже подключался по https. А если вас устраивает http, то не нужно

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html